# Show that $(A, B) \text{ and } \left(\frac{X_1}{S_3}, \frac{X_1+X_2}{S_3}\right)$ have the same joint distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

We leet $X, X_1, X_2,...$ be iid with $\mathbb{P}(X>t) = e^{-t}$ for $t >0$. Let $S_n = X_1+\cdots+ X_n$. Now Let $U, V$ be independent uniform on $[0, 1]$ Let $A = \min(U, V)$ and $B = \max(U, V)$. Show that
\begin{equation}
        (A, B) \text{ and } \left(\frac{X_1}{S_3}, \frac{X_1+X_2}{S_3}\right)
    \end{equation}
have the same joint distribution.

My approach is that we have to verify for any constants $a, b \in [0, 1]$,

\begin{equation}
            P(A\leq a, B \leq b) = P\left(\frac{X_1}{S_3} \leq a, \frac{X_1+X_2}{S_3}\leq b\right)
 \end{equation}

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: This is a cool question. I’ve come across it in a course, stated as “in a Poisson process $N(t)$, the distribution of the jumping times $T_n$ conditional on $N(t)=n$ is distributed as the order statistics of $n$ independent $U[0,t]$ random variables”. I’d love to see if someone comes up with a different or simpler approach. It’s currently late at night so I may be late to respond.

Answer (score 1):

The joint density of $(S_1,S_2,S_3)$ is
$$f(x,y,z)=e^{-x}e^{-(y-x)}e^{-(z-y)}=e^{-z}$$ for $0<x<y<z$ and zero elsewhere.
Integrating $dx dy$ we find the density of $S_3$ is $f_{S_3}(z)=z^2e^{-z}/2$ for $z>0$
(this is a $\Gamma(3,1)$ distribution, see [1]). Thus the conditional density of
$(S_1, S_2)$ given $S_3$  is the density ratio $2/z^2$ for $0<x<y<z$. In other words, given $S_3=z$, the pair $(S_1,S_2)$ is uniformly distributed  on the triangle
$\{(x,y): 0<x<y<z \}$. It follows that, given $S_3=z$, the pair
$(S_1/S_3,\, S_2/S_3)$ is uniformly distributed  on the triangle
$\{(x,y): 0<x<y<1\}$, with constant conditional density 2. Since this distribution does not depend on $z$, it is also the (unconditional) joint distribution of  $(S_1/S_3,\, S_2/S_3)$. Clearly, this is also the joint distribution of $(A,B)$. See also Theorem 6.6(d) in [2].

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

[2] [https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~dasgupta/orderstats.pdf](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Edasgupta/orderstats.pdf)